# How to set ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY using C# bindings?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I´m using Official .NET Bindings for ZeroMQ (x86) 2.2.5 and cannot figure out how to set this Socket Option. Can anyone please shed some light on me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLRZMQ is obsolete, NetMQ(https://github.com/zeromq/netmq) is now the official  stack for windows.

in NetMQ use socket.Options.Mandatory = true;

Comment: Thanks! I´ll use NetMQ for windows, but can i use NetMQ under mono safely ?

Comment: Yes, you can use NetMQ with mono.

Answer (score 0):

CLRZMQ **is not** obsolete (see [zeromq.org](http://zeromq.org/bindings:clr)). The key difference between the two is in the approach:

- CLRZMQ is *binding* project which actually uses `libzmq` library in background (it's a .NET wrapper for `libzmq` library);
- NetMQ is .NET-native port of ZeroMQ, meaning that it does not wrap existing `libzmq` but *rewrites it* in pure C#.

Which one to use? Well, there's no simple answer. Here are few important things to keep in mind while choosing:

- When it comes to portability - NetMQ wins by far, especially due to the fact that there's .NET Core version of NetMQ. Deployment is also easier with NetMQ - there are no native libraries to worry about (x64 / x86, etc.).
- On the other side the fact that NetMQ actually rewrites everything is bit scary for me - there's always risk that something is not precisely mirrored from the original code, and that it may cause incompatibility with other ZeroMQ nodes. There's also question how fast NetMQ will implement new features from the original library.
- Performances. At the moment I don't know which library wins in performances, but this is definitely thing to consider while choosing. `libzmq` should be significantly faster than any managed code, but in communication between CLRZMQ and `libzmq` marshaling has to take place, so I really can't predict which library will win in speed.